# Ansible replace module regexp starting with '$'

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7, replace, ansible

I'm trying to use `replace` module from Ansible, and I don't know how to match some string using `regexp`.

I'm trying to match a string starting with the character `$` but ansible keeps saying that he `found unknown escape character '$'`.

I know that ansible use the same regexp rules from python, but I can't do it in python as well, do you guys know how to do it?

I have tried already these regexp rules:

`^\$`, `[!^$]`, `[!^$]` and `\s*[!^$]`

The last 3 rules matches with strings starting with `$` but if the string doesn't start with `$`, matches with those srings too.

some examples for the last 3 rules:

```
foo        doesn't match
$foo       match
$$$$       match
foo$       match
foo$bar    match
```

I need to match only in this cases:

```
foo
$foo       this case
$$$$       this case
foo$
foo$bar
```

Comment: this should work on your case: '^\$.*$'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `re.match`

**Demo:**

```
import re
l = ["foo", "$foo", "$$$$", "foo$", "foo$bar"]
for i in l:
    print(re.match("^\$", i))
```

**Output:**

```
None
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x0000000001D84578>
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x0000000001D84578>
None
None
```

And in Ansible try using `regex_search`.

Comment: Thanks Rakesh, let me ask you, there is no way to use regex_search in the replace module, in the regexp field?